# How to store an object and its row/column position + have an index

Tags: c#-4.0

I am making a space invaders game. Each invader has its position on the screen stored. This would form a nice grid of 5 rows with each 11 invaders.

There are 3 types of invader A, B, and C. A consists of 22 invaders, B also, and C 11. Because of this I could not use their positions alone to form the grid on the screen. So, I added variables for how many rows and columns there are and with these I could use a nested for loop to get the right amount of invadertypes.

Now, I have an idea for some kind of algorithm to get them to do something, but for that I need to store them in a certain way. How I'm thinking of doing it is to use a `Dictionary<int, Tuple<Point, Invader>>`, where int will be the index like in a list, Point will be used for storing row-column, and Invader for well, the invader.

Before I used a List to store invaders and so I could with a **for** loop access the invader I needed to perform an operation on. Like **invaders[i].*DoSomething()***.

I want to be able to still do that, and have not only the invader, but also what row-column it is occupying.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Why not add  row / column variables to your invader class?

Comment: Because... because it doesn't seem to belong in the invader class? You do mean to store the row/column where a particular invader is in the invader itself? Just like it's position?

Comment: Yea im not sure exactly how your invader class looks etc but if i were doing this I would possibly consider having the invaders position in the invader class itself.

Comment: Well, I already have their position on the screen stored away in the invader. I just.. I don't know, feel that their row/column position shouldn't be stored in there as well. More that it should be stored in the collection where the invaders are stored. Hence my question of how I could do this :-)

Comment: Does their Row / column number ever change?